# Fill the missing number

Tags: pattern

[image]

The options are:

1. 49
2. 50
3. 60
4. 69

Yes, Yes, I know about Puzzling's policy and all that. No, this is **not** from any ongoing contest. I can't provide a source simply because this was a randomly generated question on a website which I was using.

Comment: But are you *really* sure it's not? ;)

Comment: @n_palum Pretty sure. ;)

Comment: 69, because you should always go for that if it's one of the options. *wink, wink*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with

> 69

Because

> In all a,b and c the numbers opposite to each other add up to the same sum.

Explanation:

> A: $29 + 43 = 39 + 33 = 45 + 27 = 72$
>  B: $29 + 44 = 42 + 31 = 43 + 30 = 73$
>  C: $59 + 20 = 39 + 40 = ? + 10 = 79$  hence $? = 69$.

Note:

> I have no idea what the numbers in the middle of each section mean.

Bonus:

> as stated in my comment on the question... You should always go for 69 if you have the option.

Comment: Ah, so the numbers at the centre were all red herrings? I should have figured this out myself instead of troubling all you geniuses. Thank you.

Comment: @Sid. I added an explanation.

Comment: Hey, watch it. No need for name calling. Who you calling a genius?

Comment: Point taken. The next time I see 69, I am going to mark that. If it is wrong, you are to blame. :P